# Check for blank cell using cell reference

Tags: java, apache-poi

I've been writing a code in POI to enter data into an Excel sheet. Here first I need to loop through a set of rows, I'm not sure how many of them are there, might be 10 or 100. But I found that there is a blank cell at the end. And after that blank again there are a set of rows. I'm not bothered about that second set. I need to find if the first set has ended or not.

This is pretty confusing. Right now I've 5 users in my sheet like below. After the 5th user there is a blank cell. I'm trying to print all the users if there is a blank stop it.

```
AAA
BBB
CCC
DDD
EEE

JJJ
```

I'm using the below code to do this job.

```
String userName;
CellReference ref = null;
Row row;
Cell cell;
do {
    userName = "B" + i;
        ref = new CellReference(userName);
        row = sheet.getRow(ref.getRow());
        cell = row.getCell(ref.getCol());
        System.out.println(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t" + userName);
        i++;
} while (row != null);
```

But the output that I get is as below.

```
AAA     B4
BBB     B5
CCC     B6
DDD     B7
EEE     B8
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at FinalSheetFillData.main(FinalSheetFillData.java:26)
```

Where am I going wrong and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to check cellRow value and then system.out

```
String userName;
CellReference ref = null;
Row row;
Cell cell;
do {
    userName = "B" + i;
        ref = new CellReference(userName);
        row = sheet.getRow(ref.getRow());
        cell = row.getCell(ref.getCol());
        if(cell.getStringCellValue()!=null){
            System.out.println(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t" + userName);
        }else{
            System.out.println(" " + "\t" + userName);
        }
        i++;
} while (row != null);
```

Comment: Still giving me the same error, but thistime it shifted above like 
`AAA B4
BBB  B5
Exception in thread "main" CCC B6
DDD B7
EEE B8
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at FinalSheetFillData.main(FinalSheetFillData.java:26)`

Comment: Maybe the `cell` variable is null?  If line 26 is `if(cell.getStringCellValue()!=null){` Then try checking if `cell` is null, instead of `cell.getStringCellValue()`  -- see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31184499/apache-poi-getcell-error-java-lang-nullpointerexception-cannot-read-cell-if?rq=1

Comment: Row will never equal null, even on the line you are reading, it is not null. It is "\n".

Comment: If a row is missing, that is, has no cells with data, then it will be null, and row.getCell() will fail. This is always a possibility when you are reading a row by index.

Answer (score 1):

`Sheet.getRow()` will return a null if the row is missing from the sheet. And, blank rows are frequently missing. The situation with cells and `Row.getCell()`. So once you get to cell `B9`, the code is bombing at `if(cell.getStringCellValue()` because `cell` is `null`. You can loop with a `for each` construct to avoid these issues, or you can use a regular `for` loop in this situation since you are looking for a missing row to stop processing.

```
String userName;
CellReference ref = null;
Row row;
Cell cell;
for (int i = sheet.getFirstRow(); i <= sheet.getLastRow(); i++) {
    userName = "B" + i;
    ref = new CellReference(userName);
    row = sheet.getRow(ref.getRow());
    if (row != null) {
        cell = row.getCell(ref.getCol());
        if(cell != null && !cell.toString().trim().equals("")){
            System.out.println(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t" + userName);
        }else{
            break;
        }
     } else {
        break;
     }
}
```